# Disable Visual Studio 2008 Conversion Wizard for VSTO

Tags: visual-studio-2008, wizard

Is it possible to deactivate the VS 2008 conversion wizard. I want to open a solution that contains VSTO project for Office 2003 and I don't want them to be converted when I open the solution on a PC with Office 2007.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the VS2008 options found here...

Tools -> Options -> Office Tools -> Project Upgrade

Try clearing the option *Always upgrade to the installed version of Office*.

Is that what you are looking for?