# VSTO Outlook Project and Conversion Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2008, vsto, outlook-2003, conversion-wizard

I have a VSTO - Office 2003 project. Written in .Net 3.5/C#/Visual Studio 2008.

It has been a very long time since I have accessed the project, but a client needed an update made to it, so I loaded my XP/Office 2003/VS 2008 VM, and opened the project. It then asked me to upgrade my project and loaded the conversion wizard.

I followed the selected [answer for a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945316/disable-visual-studio-2008-conversion-wizard-for-vsto/945363#945363), but it didn't solve the problem, and Office 2007 isn't installed. This VM was the development VM before.

Also, once the project is converted, it says that I don't have the version of Office needed to run the project.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to check the targeted Outlook version. You can do this from your addin proj file.

```
<ProjectProperties HostName="Outlook" HostPackage="{20A848B8-E01F-4801-962E-25DB0FF57389}" OfficeVersion="14.0" VstxVersion="4.0" ApplicationType="Outlook" Language="cs" TemplatesPath="VSTOTemplates" DebugInfoExeName="#Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\InstallRoot\Path#outlook.exe" AddItemTemplatesGuid="{66FE057A-6BD5-4A46-8060-3C3E596574A0}" />
```

Here we can see that the version is 14 (outlook 2010): OfficeVersion="14.0"
To change it for Outlook 2007 you need to change OfficeVersion to 12.0 . For 2003 i think is 11 tho i didn't worked on 2003. Also, don't forget to change it in the DebugInfoExeName with the appropiate version